# Remove Grub 2 Blockfiles from Partition eg. /dev/sda1

Tags: linux, boot, truecrypt, grub2

In the process of setting up an encrypted Windows partition along with a dual booting Ubuntu, I have had to install the GRUB bootloader onto a partition `/dev/sda1` instead of the MBR. 
In this setup `/dev/sda1` is a Dell recovery partition.

It actually works fine believe it or not.  I have written [**basic pointers**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10426936&postcount=2).

To a point. On the system I was testing this on, I ended up with GRUB installed on two partitions, `sda1` and `sda2`. Is there a way to remove the GRUB blockfiles from one of these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean removing the `grub` boot sector so that it won't boot from it? It is just the first sector in your drive or partition.

Backup, be very cautious!

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=1 of=sda1.bootsector.backup
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=1
```

Comment: Aha I think that's what I'm looking for. Am I right in thinking this should have no effect on the partition itself, as long as it is not windows (ie. Dell system recovery partition)?

Comment: yes, filesystems should not be using the boot block in any event.

Comment: +1 for recommending to back it up before doing anything with it. I've seen people in IRC say "oops" then fight with it for a while. Definitely easier to say `dd if=/home/user/backups/sda1.boot.bkup of=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=1` and have it fixed.